# Why can't I use multiplication rule to calculate probability here?

Tags: probability

This is a fairly straight forward problem:

"Two design teams, A and B, are both asked to design a working prototype. Based on past experience

1. the probability that team A is successful is 2/3;
2. the probability that team B is successful is 1/2;
3. the probability that at least one team is successful is 3/4;

What's the probability that team A fails and team B succeeds?"

The solution is 1/12, with explanation below:

```
P(at least one team is successful) = P(A=1,B=1)+P(A=0,B=1)+P(A=1,B=0) = 3/4
P(team A is successful) = P(A=1,B=1)+P(A=1,B=0) = 2/3
P(team A fails and team B succeeds) = P(A=0,B=1) = P(A=1,B=1)+P(A=0,B=1)+P(A=1,B=0)-(P(A=1,B=1)+P(A=1,B=0)) = 3/4-2/3 = 1/12
```

So my question is, why can't I simply use the multiplication rule here (since A fails and B succeeds are independent) and say
`P(A=0,B=1) = P(A=0)*P(B=1) = (1-2/3)*(1/2) = 1/6`     ???

Comment: Because A fails and B succeeds aren't independent?

Comment: now I see that they aren't independent...so does the product `P(A=0)*P(B=1)=1/6` still mean anything?

Comment: No, no immediate meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they AREN'T independent, as given by "the probability that at least one team is successful is 3/4".

Comment: could u plz elaborate more on why "the probability that at least one team is successful is 3/4" reveals dependence in this case?

Comment: If the two were independent, you would get a different probability.

Comment: which would be 5/6 in that case?

Comment: Something like that. If independent, it's $(2/3)*(1/2)+(2/3)*(1/2)+(1/3)*(1/2)=5/6$. So yup, you're correct.